# Monthly rent invoice and payments database schema

Tags: php, mysql, database, schema

I am trying to make a schema for my application. My application is about the property (house/flat) rent management.

The big confusion I am facing right now is how to implement the monthly payments and keep record of those payments for later on reports. Plus those payments must be integrateable with invoices. It's kind of too confusing and in database section I am not much of an expert.

There is a lot of help regarding coding online, but really creating a schema I am not sure how one can learn to make so complex schemas.

I have most of tables. Plus created payments table, where there is

```
paymentID,
TenantID,
TotalDues,
PaymentRecieved, //Amount Recieved for the current month dues
PaymentRemaining, //If not fully paid the dues and still remaining..
DateRecieved,
etc etc..
```

It's just a simple table but I am really confused how to make it more flexible so that if tenant don't pays the rent at all this month then should get total rent in next month. Or if rent was paid this month half or some amount of it then should keep track of it for next month.

What should I do to make this system more flexible and have invoice system introduced?

---

**UPDATE:**

From some answers I gathered I would need to create another table to keep record.

So we would have:

```
payment_record/Invoice
------------------------------
RecordID | Payment(Month/Year) | Electricity | Gas | Water | Rent | Total
   1            Jan-2015            50          30     5      80    165
```

Second table we would have

```
Payment/Transaction
------------------------------
PaymentID | RecordID(Foreign-Key) | PaymentReceived | DateReceived
   1                1                      100          2015-01-08
```

so third table would be

```
   PaymentDue/Status
   ----------------------------------
   StatusID | PaymentID(Foreign-Key) | PaymentRemaining
      1             1                          65
```

Is there something I am missing, or do I have what's needed to start coding?

Still I am unsure about one more thing. What would in case I do, if tenant pays for current month some amount and after two days he pays more for current month. How would I manage that?

Do I need to make another entry in the `paymentdue` and `payment/transaction` table?

Comment: First tip: you can remove `PaymentRemaining` since this can be derived from the payment required minus `payments.PaymentRecieved`.

Comment: To keep track of what is owed, perhaps you could add a `payment_due` table? If rent is due every month, create a record here for the amount due. You will probably need a daily timer system to add any due records for tenants. To work out the total due, you can do `SUM(payment.due)`, filtering by the tenant in question.

Comment: (Fix spelling of `DateRecieved` -> `DateReceived`).

Comment: I don't think `TotalDues` belongs in `payments`, since records here are made when a payment is made, but a payment is due regardless of whether a payment has been made. This value is just for the current month, right? You don't want to store the totals here, as they are available via `SUM()`.

Comment: @halfer
Thankyou sir for replies..
i got the idea that i am doing the wrong way should create two tables..
but how would invoice jumps in it. i means invoice is created before the payment is made?
so first i would do entry in invoice and if payment is done then do entry in these two tables??

Comment: Ah, if you have an `invoice` then maybe that would do the same thing as my `payment_due` table. Please add in all relevant table schemas into your question.

Comment: @halfer
sorry for incomplete question, i updated my question sir.

Comment: You probably should have TenantID replacing StatusID in the "paymentDue" table, the paymentID is optional. For partial payment, you simply add another record in "transaction" table, and update "paymentDue" accordingly. The basic rule is, always INSERT new entries for "transaction" and "invoice". For paymentDue, always update the entry if the same tenantID already exist, insert if it doesn't.

Comment: @JackyCheng
Thankyou sir, Got your Point..

Answer (score 2):

You need to solve the problem by looking at the schema AND the query statement you gonna use at the same time.

From your sample, i realize you want to have a table that tracks everything, which is totally doable. However it'd require complex insert statement or stored-procedures to constantly update that table.

For the sake of simplicity, try splitting it into 2 tables. This should eliminate the need to retroactively updating previous records. It will also keep all the query for tenant status a lot quicker due to the separation. The first simply contains static records of payments:

```
paymentID,TenantID,PaymentRecieved,DateRecieved,.....
```

The other contains the status of tenant

```
TenantID,PaymentRemaining,LatestPaymentID(or date),...
```

Every time a tenant pays rent, insert 1 static record and update the status table accordingly. A simply version of the update SQL for status table could be like below. Make sure you add checking to things like PaymentRemaining - $payment and not letting it goes into negative(Or maybe let it goes into negative so tenant pay less next month?)

```
INSERT INTO status VALUES ($tenantId,$monthlyRent-$payment,$paymentID) ON DUPLICATE KEY 
    UPDATE PaymentRemaining = PaymentRemaining - $payment, LatestPaymentID = $paymentID;
```

For your monthly payment/balance check simply look at the second table.

Comment: Thankyou sir, for response.
So according to this concept i will make two entries in both tables everytime or just do entry in other table when there is some remaining balance.

Comment: Also, do i need to make an invoice table and if so invoice table will get data before this table right??
plz don't mind, new to this accounting section that's why asking many questions..

Comment: Everytime someone pays, insert 1 entry into the first static table "payment_record" . The purpose of that table is to simply keep record. Then use `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...` for the "tenant_status" table to update its remaining balance. The "tenant_status" should have 1 entry per tenant and has the most up to date balance.

Comment: and what about invoice, which can be email to or printed for tenant.
i mean invoice would contain balance remaing, and list of services for which amount is added in total.. e-g electricity amount or gas etc will be sum..
for that what would be the best way to manage.
should i make column in these tables or should i create another table of invoice?

Comment: oh so you have things like electricity bill. In that case simply add another table like "payment_record" but for electricity. Everytime a electricity bill comes in, insert a record into "elec_bill" table and update the "tenant_status" table by adding that amount to the balance remaining

Comment: the "elec_bill" table would be something like `elecBillID,TenantID,Amount,BillDate,.....` you could do the same for gas etc

Comment: @Sizzling: it is best to add all relevant information to your question in one go, rather that adding more and more problems for people to consider. Please add what you want to know about how to handle utility bills into the text of the question (whilst also ensuring you are not asking multiple questions - we also ask that, broadly, each question post contains only one question. You may need to ask another question if the section about utility bills is really a separate problem).

Comment: Sir, i updated my question to clear the doubts i have about payments and processing..